# clearTimeout when tool.mouseMove event starts (PaperJs, VueJs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, timeout, paperjs

I have a Paper instance with a tool that just draws a path on mouseMove and deletes the segments at the start of that path if the number of segments is greater than 50. Everything works perfect this far. this is the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import paper from 'paper';

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
  },
  created() {
    paper.install(window);
  },
  mounted() {
    const canvas = this.$el.querySelector('#canvas');
    paper.setup(canvas);
    const path = new Path();
    path.strokeColor = '#f5bb56';
    path.strokeWidth = 2;
    this.tool = new Tool()
    this.tool.onMouseMove = event => {
      if (path.segments.length > 50) {
        path.removeSegment(0)
      };
      path.add(event.point);
      path.smooth({
        type: 'continuous'
      });
    };
    view.draw()
  },
};
</script>
<style lang="scss">
  #canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

The problem is that now i want to start deleting segments from that path with an interval of 50 miliseconds but stop executing that when a new segment is added. I'm looking for something to set a variable into a timeout(() => {eraseFunction()}), when the event is not fired for about two seconds.

i added a clearTimeout pointing to the variable that contains it at the start of the mouseMove event and setting it at the end, so if there's a timeout running, i remove it when the mouseMove starts:

```
export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tool: null,
      path: null,
      erase: null,
    }
  },
  created() {
    paper.install(window);
  },
  mounted() {
    const canvas = this.$el.querySelector('#canvas');
    paper.setup(canvas);
    this.path = new Path();
    this.path.strokeColor = '#f5bb56';
    this.path.strokeWidth = 2;
    this.tool = new Tool()
    this.tool.onMouseMove = event => {
      clearTimeout(this.erase);
      if (this.path.segments.length > 50) {
        this.path.removeSegment(0)
      };
      this.path.add(event.point);
      this.path.smooth({
        type: 'continuous'
      });
      this.erase = setTimeout(() => {
        this.eraseFunction()
      }, 2000);
    };
    view.draw()
  },
  methods: {
    eraseFunction() {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.path.removeSegment(0);
      }, 500);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

the problem is that the timeout is not removed and given a certain amount of time, i can´t draw new segments because they´re deleted inmediately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear **setInterval** also. You are only clearing setTimeout. setInterval is still running an deleting your segments.

Answer (score 1):

ClearInterval need the intervalID you want to clear. The intervalID is given by setInterval call.

You should return the result of setTimout call in eraseFunction:

```
eraseFunction() {
      return setInterval(() => {
        this.path.removeSegment(0);
      }, 500);
    }
```

And you should assign to this.erase the result of eraseFunction call, instead of the setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        this.erase = this.eraseFunction()
      }, 2000);
```